# LIve USB not booting

Tags: boot, 12.04, live-usb

I've downloaded an ISO file of Ubuntu 12.04 and created a Live USB but when I try to boot from USB this Error comes up.

`"BOOT ERROR"`

What should I Do?

Comment: How did did you create it?  I use UNetbootin and it works for me.
Also did you check the md5sum of the .iso?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is usually not with the ISO or with the USB creator but with the BIOS itself.

To fix this problem, go to Bios Boot Menu and search for *USB Mass Storage Emulation type*.

Change `Default: Auto` to `All Fixed Disc` or something similar.

Comment: I don't have any [similar] option like this in my BIOS...

Answer (score 0):

Most sources on the net seem to blame the BIOS for this, but in my case I was able to solve the problem by formatting the USB drive to ext4 rather than the usually suggested fat32. Even if this doesn't work, perhaps try some different formats (ext2, ntfs, whatever)

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Please do some research and elaborate when posting answers. Random "this kinda sorta worked for me and it could mayhaps kinda work some other way" is of no aid to an asker, if they have no way of qualifying "Why doesn't it work for me?" "How could I fix that?".